# Python Package and Optional Package Requirements

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I've designed a package that requires another python package, but there are some in my group that would like to make this package optional.

Does anyone have any suggestions/best practices on how handle optional packages?

I was thinking of doing this:

```
try:
    import package
    allowFunctions = True
except:
     allowFunctions = False
```

Is this the best way to do handle package checking?

To make this not a duplicate, which I think it isn't, where should the check occur in the package?  Should it occur int he main **init**.py for the package folder?  Can all the other subpackages/modules pull from that **init**.py file the checked variable name?

Comment: Yup, that's the best way.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that way used a lot.